# Is there a way to Align Rotation to the X Axis after snapping objects from the asset Browser with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

So I've tried to use a GN nodes setup to make the Texts Align to the X Axis several diffrent ways, but no matter what I try, Pulling the same object in Asset Browser the Texts do not want to Align to the new scene's X Axis.

[image]

Is there any solution to this that I may have missed?